# How to get the float values after particular symbol using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary

I am new to python, I have been using regex for matching, etc. Now I am facing a small issue with it, I have a string `str = "vans>=20.09 and stands == 'four'"`. I want the values after the Comparison Operators, I have used regex to extract that the pattern which I gave is working fine in extracting the values like int and strings but it is not extracting the float values. What is the best pattern, so that regex will extract all kind of values(int, float, strings)?

My code:

```
import re
str = "vans>=20.09 and stands == 'four'" 
rx = re.compile(r"""(?P<key>\w+)\s*[<>=]+\s*'?(?P<value>\w+)'?""")
result = {m.group('key'): m.group('value') for m in rx.finditer(str)}
```

which gives:

```
{'vans': '20', 'stands': 'four'}
```

Expected Output:

```
{'vans': '20.09', 'stands': 'four'}
```

Comment: I think you need `rx = re.compile(r"""(?P<key>\w+)\s*[<>=]+\s*'?(?P<value>\d*\.?\d+|\w+)'?""")`, see the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mG6UKN).

Comment: and if `\d` does not include `\.` then you might want to make it `[\d.]*` or such if you dont want to match more than 1 `\.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the second `\w` group with an `\.` to include dots.

```
rx = re.compile(r"""(?P<key>\w+)\s*[<>=]+\s*'?(?P<value>[\w\.]+)'?""")
```

This should work fine, strings like `12.34.56` will also be matched as value.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in identifying the comparison operators as well. The following should suffice all use cases. However, there is a caveat - for numbers with no digit following the decimal, only the value before the decimal point will be selected.

```py
rx = re.compile(r"""(?P<key>\w+)\s*[<>!=]=\s*'?(?P<value>(\w|[+-]?\d*(\.\d)?\d*)+)'?""")
```